# How do I access a route parameter in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

## Query string parameter

I have seen plenty of examples of reading query string parameters.

For example take the following URI:

`/api/Profile?id={accountId}`

The `accountId` can be read in the policy xml using the following syntax:

`context.Request.Url.Query["accountId"]`

## Route parameter

But what if my URI is structured as:

`/api/profiles/{accountId}`

How do I read `accountId` in the policy xml when the parameter is not in the query string?

Answer (score 3):

Using the example above I can read the `accountId` by the following syntax:

`context.Request.MatchedParameters["accountId"]`

For example I could assign it to a variable for usage elsewhere in the APIM policy file:

`<set-variable name="account-id" value="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["accountId"])" />`

There isn't a massive amount of documentation about it, but thankfully there is at least [some mention of the Context variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ContextVariables) on learn.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GitHub repository with quite some snippets including your use case: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/policy-expressions/README.md

For your concrete example, you can use this:

```
context.Request.MatchedParameters.GetValueOrDefault("accountId", "optional-default-value")
```

The benefit compared to the other solution is that the policy evaluation does not fail if the URI parameter does not exist. It will use the default value as a fallback instead. Otherwise a 500 Internal Server Error would be returned.